# Load template and attach chosen file

Tags: vba, outlook

The aim of this project is to:

- Load template from network personal drive (currently working)
- Open Dialog Window, using Word (as that loads quicker for me), set to a different network folder (function achieved - just)
- Choose and attach user chosen file (prefered option for multi-file selection but that was to complex and thus beyond the time I can afford to dedicate to the project)
- Using previous filepath, build and apply the subject line based on the file name. (currently working)

The macro is called by a button in the Quick Access or Main Tool Bars.

The problems:

1. when the "Browse" window appears, it does so behind outlook/hidden UNLESS the macro code has been viewed in the editor at some time since Outlook was opened; every fix either show the entire Word program or seems to have no effect.
2. when you choose a file in the "Browse" and then click "OK", a second "Browse" window opens where you have to choose a file again and this time click "Open"; this second file is then the one that is attached to the email.**<--FIXED**

System Details (even though not all will be of importance)

```
Windows 7 64bit
Office Professional 2010
```

The Code

```
Sub New_Orders_Email()

    Dim NewMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim otherObject As Word.Application
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Dim fileaddress As String
    Dim filename As String

    On Error GoTo Final

    'Set template to use
    Set NewMail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("P:\Office Templates\Orders SCI - 1617.oft")


    'Set to use Word for Attach File Dialog
    Set otherObject = New Word.Application
    otherObject.Visible = False

    Set fd = otherObject.Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fd
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = "R:\Science\Technician Documents\Budgets & Orders\2016 - 2017\Orders\"
    .Show
    End With

    fd.Show

    fileaddress = fd.SelectedItems(1)

    'Aquire File Name in correct form for Subject Line
    Dim MidStart As Long
    MidStart = InStrRev(fileaddress, "\") + 16

    Dim MidEnd As Long
    MidEnd = InStrRev(fileaddress, ".")

    filename = Mid(fileaddress, MidStart, MidEnd - MidStart)

    'Load template, attach single file and apply correct Subject
    NewMail.Display
    NewMail.Attachments.Add (fileaddress)
    NewMail.Subject = "Order No: " + filename
    otherObject.Quit

    Set otherObject = Nothing
    Final:

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file Dialog is probably not shown, because of the line "otherObject.Visible = False"

Number (2) might be solved if you delete one of your "fd.Show". Looks like you call it twice...

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. The first part, "otherObject.Visible = False", is used to hide the main Word application (so it doesn't appear in the task bar, nor does the main Word window open, only the open dialog shows). Number (2) is now fixed, guess as I said got myself confused, the extra "fd.Show" was left over from trying to fix (1).

Comment: How do you want to call the macro? Within an own menu item? For me it works fine...

Comment: Additionally, I recommend you to delete "On Error GoTo Final" and try to catch errors by your own. E.g. check if fileaddress is NULL...

Comment: It is called by buttons in the Quick Access and Main Tool Bars. I will investigate proper error catching, the current method was implemented as the quickest and easiest method; although it just silent quits. Hmmm I wonder whats different because even implementing both your first changes still leaves the Word Application and Dialog Box opening in the background, as evidenced by Word appearing and flashing in the task bar.